# Cygwin rsync cannot run outside of Cygwin terminal

Tags: cygwin, rsync

I installed `rsync 3.2.4` with cygwin in windows11 with the path `C:\Cygwin\bin\rsync.exe`. When I directly run rsync in windows terminal, I got the error code 12.
[image]

But this command runs normally when executed in `cygwin terminal`. Are there any other configuration should I do to use `rsync` outside of `cygwin terminal`?

Comment: AFAIK cygwin programs (as opposed to mingw builds) aren't exactly native Windows programs and aren't really supposed to be run outside cygwin terminal / shell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just solve this problem by specifying the path of ssh with `-e`

Comment: You didn't post the command you were executing and what shell you were using when running the command. Note that there is no such thing as a "Cygwin terminal". You can run a shell from Cygwin (bash, zsh, ...)  inside the normal Windows terminal. However, you **can** also install with Cygwin `mintty`, which is a terminal that is optimized for Cygwin and much more powerful than the one which comes with Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found why the error happend. In `windows terminal`, `rsync` call `windows openssh` when syncing with remote server, which is incompatible with `cygwin rsync`. Just specify the `cygwin ssh path`, It could run normally. Like this

`C:\Cygwin\bin\rsync.exe -e "C:\Cygwin\bin\ssh.exe" source_file destination`.